# Backup files not found in ASM

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, rman, oracle-asm

I have an Oracle database 11gr2 and I have installed Oracle Grid on Oracle Linux 5.9. I have two disk groups.

/etc/init.d/oracleasm listdisks :

```
flash_recovery_area

DATA
```

The first disk group is mounted on `/u01` and the second is mounted on `/flash_recovery_area`.

The value of fra parameters are:

```
db_recovery_file_dest = /+flash_recovery_area

db_recovery_file_dest_size = 30G
```

When I want to connect to rman and get backup from current database, I can but I can not find anything in `/flash_recovery_area` destination.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will write all the datafiles and such to your DATA directory. You actually have to create a backup in the +flash_recovery_area you have created. What sort of backup are you trying to create?

What command are you using to create your backup?

For instance, if you wanted to execute a Level 0 IMAGE COPY, you could issue the following command:

```
backup incremental level 0 as copy database tag 'L0_COPY';
```